# How do I define implicit class that can pimp both base and derived class

Tags: scala, akka, implicit-conversion, implicit, akka-stream

How do I define implicit class that can pimp both base and derived class ?

I want to implement class that would pimp both [Flow](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.scala) and [Source](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.scala). I tried this

```
implicit class FlowOpsMatExt[T, Mat](val flow: FlowOpsMat[T, Mat]) {
  def groupSortedByKey[K](keyForItem: T ⇒ K, maxBufferSize: Int): flow.Repr[Vector[T]]
}
```

But called on instance of `Source[]` I get `FlowOpsMat` which I can no longer use as Source. So I tried to trick it

```
implicit class FlowOpsMatExt[T, Mat, C <: FlowOpsMat[T, Mat]](val flow2: C)
```

but it fails to detect types for some reason. In explicit call

```
new FlowOpsMatExt(source_instance)
```

I get following error

```
Error:(106, 5) inferred type arguments [Nothing,Nothing,akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString,akka.NotUsed]] do not conform to class FlowOpsMatExt's type parameter bounds [T,Mat,C <: akka.stream.scaladsl.FlowOpsMat[T,Mat]]
    new FlowOpsMatExt(src)
```

Minimal example to reproduce: https://gist.github.com/931a313546f14e809b705e86743dcdb0

It compiles if I specify all types explicitly `new FlowOpsMatExt[ByteString, NotUsed, Source[ByteString, NotUsed]](src)` but it kills benefit of using implicit class.

What am I missing ?

The best I could come up with is to keep implementation of extension function in abstract class and implement two implicit classes from it

```
abstract class FlowOpsMatExt[T, Mat, C <: FlowOpsMat[T, Mat]] {
  protected val flow: C
}

implicit class FlowExt2[In, Out, Mat](val flow: Flow[In, Out, Mat]) extends FlowOpsMatExt[Out, Mat, Flow[In, Out, Mat]] {
}

implicit class SourceExt[T, Mat](val flow: Source[T, Mat]) extends FlowOpsMatExt[T, Mat, Source[T, Mat]] {
}
```

Comment: What is `source_instance` in `new FlowOpsMatExt(source_instance)`? Could you provide example?

Comment: @DmytroMitin It's `Source[ByteString, NotUsed]`

Comment: You should provide more details how you make calls. I guess you don't call `new FlowOpsMatExt(source_instance)` since implicit classes are not intended for that. I guess it's something like `source_instance.groupSortedByKey ...`? Please provide examples that compiles and doesn't compile. Currently I can't figure out what is your real problem since `val source_instance: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] = ???`
`source_instance.groupSortedByKey(???, ???)` compiles.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Minimal example https://gist.github.com/931a313546f14e809b705e86743dcdb0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-customize.html#extending-flow-operators-with-custom-operators):

> Advanced Scala users may wonder whether it is possible to write extension methods that enrich `FlowOps` to allow nicer syntax. The short answer is that Scala 2 does not support this in a fully generic fashion, the problem is that it is impossible to abstract over the kind of stream that is being extended because `Source`, `Flow` and `SubFlow` differ in the number and kind of their type parameters. While it would be possible to write an implicit class that enriches them generically, this class would require explicit instantiation with all type parameters due to [SI-2712](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712). For a partial workaround that unifies extensions to Source and Flow see [this sketch by R. Kuhn](https://gist.github.com/rkuhn/2870fcee4937dda2cad5).
>
> ...
>
> It is interesting to note that a simplified form of this problem has found its way into the [dotty test suite](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/1186/files). Dotty is the development version of Scala on its way to Scala 3.